# How many ways of findind the index of objects in array?

Tags: javascript

I know how to find index of array using `indexOf` method, is there any other way like:

```
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
[{name: 'aa'},{name: 'bb'}]
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do with that code. You can't have two keys the same in an object.

Comment: I edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use findIndex method using lodash
https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#findIndex

Answer (score 1):

If you need to find more than one item, you can create a lookup:

```js
a = [ { name: 'aa' }, { name: 'bb' } ] 

for (indexes = {}, i = 0; i < a.length; i++) indexes[a[i].name] = i
   
console.log(indexes['bb'], indexes['cc'] || -1) // "1 -1"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Array.reduce() to make your custom indexOf();

```js
let arr = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];

let result = arr.reduce((a, b, i) => {
    if(a != -1) return a;
    if(b == 'bb'){
        return i;
    }
    return a;
},-1);

console.log(result);
```

here you can compare the property of b with a value. and return that index if you want to

Comment: This isn't the right use of `.reduce()`, there is a function for that: `.findIndex()`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`Array.prototype.findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/findIndex) like that:

```
const arr = ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'];
const id = arr.findIndex(item => item === 'aa');
```

For your second example `[{name: 'aa'},{name: 'bb'}]`, can you clarify what you want to do ?